# Use two connection string in application using Windsor container IOC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, castle-windsor

I am new to Castle.Windsor container. I need to access two databases and hence need two connection strings. I have added the details in the web.config file, but I'm getting an error telling the latest connection string is not registered with the container. How to register two connection strings?

Edit: from comment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="XXDB" connectionString="Data Source=XX;Integrated Security=True;Initial Catalog=XX;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
   <add name="XXLogDB" connectionString="Data Source=XX;Integrated Security=True;Initial Catalog=XXLog;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

This is the connection string in web.config .Have a conenctionstringInstaller which implements IWindsorInstaller where the first connection string is registered... When am adding the second connection string, how can i register it?

Comment: Can you show your web.config settings (not the whole file -- just the parts relevant to this question) as well as your Windsor registration code?  Including the sample code that generates the error you describe would help too.

Comment: Paste some code, please. How do you get these connection strings?

Comment: <connectionStrings>
    <add name="XXDB" connectionString="Data Source=XX;Integrated Security=True;Initial Catalog=XX;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
     <add name="XXLogDB" connectionString="Data Source=XX;Integrated Security=True;Initial Catalog=XXLog;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
   
  </connectionStrings> This is the connection string in web.config .Have a conenctionstringInstaller which implements IWindsorInstaller where the first connection string is registered... When am adding the second connection string, how can i register it?

Comment: You need to show us your ConnectionStringInstaller.